# Show users with any privileges to database. MySQL

Tags: mysql, jdbc, show, privileges

i have to select all users with any privileges to database (e.g. database 'mysql'). Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look the in `mysql` database (an actual db named `mysql` inside the mysql server, just to be clear). There's three tables (`db`, `tables_priv`, and `columns_priv`) where the db/table/column privs are stored:

```
SELECT 'db', User, Host
FROM db
WHERE Db='mydatabase'

UNION

SELECT 'table', User, Host
FROM tables_priv
WHERE Db='mydatabase'

UNION

SELECT 'col', User, Host
FROM columns_priv
WHERE Db='mydatabase'
```

should show you what you need.

Answer (score 26):

A good view of all users and their approximate privileges. If there is a password, it will by an encrytped string; if not, this field is blank. Select is a very general privlege; insert allows table manipulation within a database; shutdown allows major system changes, and should only be usable by root; the ability to grant permissions is separate from the others.

```
SELECT user, host, password, select_priv, insert_priv, shutdown_priv, grant_priv 
FROM mysql.user
```

View permissions for individual databases.

```
SELECT user, host, db, select_priv, insert_priv, grant_priv FROM mysql.db
```

Answer (score 13):

- [database privileges](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html#grant-database-privileges) are stored in `mysql.db`
- [table privileges](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html#grant-table-privileges) are stored in `mysql.tables_priv`
- [column privileges](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html#grant-column-privileges) are stored in `mysql.columns_priv`
- [routine privileges](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html#grant-routine-privileges) are stored in `mysql.proc_privs`

You can define a store procedure to list the privileges:

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE list_privileges (IN db_name CHAR(50))
BEGIN
    SELECT concat(Db,'.', '*') as 'what', User, Host, '...' as 'perms'
    FROM mysql.db
    WHERE Db=db_name
    UNION
    SELECT concat(Db,'.', Table_name), User, Host, table_priv
    FROM mysql.tables_priv
    WHERE Db=db_name and table_priv != ''
    UNION
    SELECT concat(Db,'.', Table_name, '(', Column_name,')'), User, Host, Column_priv
    FROM mysql.columns_priv
    WHERE Db=db_name
    UNION
    SELECT concat(Db,'.', Routine_name, '()'), User, Host, Proc_priv
    FROM mysql.procs_priv
    WHERE Db=db_name;
END//

delimiter ;
```

example:

```
mysql> call list_privileges("testlink2");
+-----------------------------+-----------+-----------+---------+
| what                        | User      | Host      | perms   |
+-----------------------------+-----------+-----------+---------+
| testlink2.*                 | testlink2 | %         | ...     |
| testlink2.*                 | testlink2 | localhost | ...     |
| testlink2.executions        | testlink2 | %         | Select  |
| testlink2.users(id)         | testlink2 | %         | Select  |
| testlink2.list_privileges() | testlink2 | %         | Execute |
+-----------------------------+-----------+-----------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```